# Odd order of an element

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $a,b\in G$, where $G$ is a group. $a$ had odd order, $aba^{-1}=b^{-1}$. Show that $b^2=e$

Can someone please help me with the fact that $a$ has odd order? Where does this fact point to?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: What happens if you repeatedly conjugate by $a$, starting from $b$?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft what happens? do you mean, $aba^{-1}=b?\to b=b^{-1}=e$?

Comment: So $aba^{-1} = b^{-1}$. What if you conjugate by $a$ once more? What do you get on the two sides?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft $a(aba^{-1})a^{-1}=(aba^{-1})^{-1}=ab^{-1}a^{-1}$? what does this give tho?

Comment: Right, so on the left side you have $(a^2)b(a^2)^{-1}$ and on the right side you have $b$ now. What happens if you repeat?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft $a^3ba^{-3}=b^{-1}$

Comment: Ok, now repeat until you get to $a^n$ where $n$ is the order of $a$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I see. thanks a lot man. appreciate it

Comment: There is also a more systematic way to do things like this if you are familiar with group actions.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft may i ask some quick questions too?

Comment: Sure, but it would probably be easier if you join the chat http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics

Comment: Should I ask it in general discussion?